# How to solve window load event issue in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have used `$(window).load` in my project, when my page got loads first time, it works fine. But when my page loads from cache or reload quickly then code written inside `$(window).load` function does not works. How to solve this issue?

code in window.load

```
$(window).load(function () {
    selectedfacode = '<?php echo isset($fmvrf_info)?$fmvrf_info["facode"]:''; ?>';
    if (selectedfacode > 0) {
        $('#facode option[value="' + selectedfacode + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    }
});
//also tried with
$("#facode").ajaxComplete(function () {
    selectedfacode = '<?php echo isset($fmvrf_info)?$fmvrf_info["facode"]:''; ?>';
    if (selectedfacode > 0) {
        $('#facode option[value="' + selectedfacode + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: It should actualy work, can you show us the code that is not working?

Comment: And what are the code in `$(window).load`?

Comment: Isn't $(document).ready() the more usual way of kicking off scripts in jQuery?  Maybe it would help if you dropped in an alert at he start and at the end of the code you want to execute on page load to see if it fires

Comment: @GordonM yes or $(function(){ }) as the shorter version :)

Comment: i have checked with alert. just removed alert to show code here

Comment: actually my ajax works in $(document) function which gets all option for #facode and then in window load function i have code to choose one option as selected.

Comment: Tried attaching `.ajaxComplete` to `document` `$(document).on("ajaxComplete")` ?

Comment: read docs `As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document`

Comment: Just to be sure we're being thorough,  is $fmvrf_info available to the server side before the script is generated? (or is PHP generating the script properly?)

Comment: that works fine no issue of $fmvrf_info

Comment: @ImranQamer As a follow-up. Can't you just prevent it from being cached? You're using PHP to generate it anyway so it's probably not good if it's cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your technique as below to achieve what you want.
First of all set your variable value same as you did but instead of '' string set it as 0 for minimum.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    selectedfacode = '<?php echo isset($fmvrf_info)?$fmvrf_info["facode"]:0; ?>';
});
```

Now your ajax code should run to get your data for drop down like:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: "",
     url: "urlhere",
     success: function(result){
         //set your result as option list of your drop down as u explained above in comments.
         //here main work is call to a function which make an option selected as per the value you set in variable.
         setSelectedOpt();
     }
});
```

Your setSelectedOpt function here which will make an option as selected from options list based on your variable value.

```
function setSelectedOpt(){
    //put if condition inside this function like:
    if( typeof selectedfacode !== 'undefined' && selectedfacode>0)
    {
     $('#facode option[value="' + selectedfacode + '"]').prop('selected', true);
     selectedfacode = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: have tried it but could not achieve , may be any error or mistake, let me give it a try again.

Comment: thanks man!, i was missing selectedfacode = 0 and typeof selectedfacode !== 'undefined' when i tried this technique, but now its achieved what i wanted, thanks again.

Comment: still i want to get an aswer that if i can achieve all of this by technique which i have used above, is it possible?

Comment: thanx @devpro bro for your appreciation :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a logic error where you compare `if (selectedfacode > 0)` because `selectedfacode` is defined as a string (`''` at a minimum, if no output returned from the PHP server script) and `String > 0` will return `false` in JavaScript.

I suggest you check the string's length instead.

**You code before the fix: it will never select a value in `#facode`**

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  selectedfacode = 'br';
  if (selectedfacode > 0) {
    alert("WILL NEVER GET HERE");
    $('#facode option[value="' + selectedfacode + '"]').prop('selected', true);
  }
  console.log("Can a string be > 0 in JavaScript? Answer: " + ("a string" > 0) + "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='facode'>
  <option value='bl'>Blondes</option>
  <option value='br'>Brunettes</option>
</select>
```

**Your code after the fix: checking the string `length > 0`**

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  selectedfacode = 'br';
  if (selectedfacode.length > 0) {
    $('#facode option[value="' + selectedfacode + '"]').prop('selected', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='facode'>
  <option value='bl'>Blondes</option>
  <option value='br'>Brunettes</option>
</select>
```

Next steps: after you fix this issue (assuming it was not an error introduced while copying and pasting into the question) if you still are having problems that vary between full load and cache hit it may be a timing issue. For example, if you are loading the `select` element via AJAX you should obviously wait until it is loaded before trying to select an option, etc.

Comment: Simple: call the `option selected` code after you load the items into the `select`.

Comment: Vote for explanation